# Haskell issue (Couldn't match type 'IO Integer' with 'Int')

Tags: haskell

I have a problem with a Haskell script. I'm trying to learn Haskell through doing problems I find online. The input I get is:
    Int -> Number of test cases
    S1 -> String 1 for each test case
    S2 -> String 2 for each test case

Each S1 and S2 is a space delimited string of numbers. I convert them to a list of Ints with the function `strToIntList`. I then want to process the two lists and return an integer value based on the results. I get the following error: `Couldn't match type 'IO Integer' with 'Int'` on line 24 and I stared for ages but just can't figure out why (full error at end of post).

If someone could explain why I'm going wrong, I would be very grateful.

This is my script:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

main = do
    cases <- readLn
    doLoop cases

toInt x = read x :: Int

strToIntList s = [read x :: Int | x <- (splitOn " " s)]

minOfTwo :: Int
minOfTwo = do
    sa <- getLine
    sb <- getLine
    return $ minimum [1..50]
    -- return $ minimum $ strToIntList sa

doLoop 0 = return ()
doLoop loopIndex = do
    q <- getLine
    let c = minOfTwo
    print(c)
    doLoop (loopIndex-1)
```

This is the full error I'm getting:

```
Couldn't match type `IO Integer' with `Int'
Expected type: IO String -> (String -> IO Integer) -> Int
  Actual type: IO String -> (String -> IO Integer) -> IO Integer
In a stmt of a 'do' block: sa <- getLine
In the expression:
  do { sa <- getLine;
       sb <- getLine;
       return $ minimum [1 .. 50] }
In an equation for `minOfTwo':
    minOfTwo
      = do { sa <- getLine;
             sb <- getLine;
             return $ minimum [1 .. 50] }
```

Comment: Your `minOfTwo` function has to have an `IO` type if it does `IO`, change it to `minOfTwo :: IO Int`.

Comment: As a side note, you'd be better off using `readMaybe` from `Text.Read` instead of `read`, since it'll return `Nothing` if it fails to parse instead of crashing your program.  This does mean that you'll have to write a bit more code to handle it, but writing a bit more code to do proper error handling is usually considered to be a good thing.  For quick one-off scripts it's fine to use unsafe functions like `read` though.

Comment: Thank you bheklilr. Because this is for a learning exercise and the input is guaranteed to be correct, I'm not too worried about input validation yet.

Answer (score 3):

The `getLine` function is in the `IO` monad, and therefore any function that calls `getLine` must also be in the `IO` monad. Change your type signature for `minOfTwo` from `Int` to `IO Int`, and that particular problem will go away.

(You'll also need to change `let c = minOfTwo` into `c <- minOfTwo`.)

There may be other errors, but this is the one causing your error message.

Comment: Thank you! Is this because when a function uses IO, the results aren't guaranteed to be the same every time it is called with the same arguments?